# System will not boot after reconfiguring keyboard-configuration and installing console-setup

Tags: boot, 16.04, keyboard

Some time ago I was trying to modify keyboard settings and after modifying files Alt key stopped working. Today I decided to fix this and restore default keyboard configuration, so I ran:

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

After that I was able to use Alt key and for example use terminal shortcut Ctrl+Alt+T, but it was not persistent across logouts. After googling I found and executed this:

```
apt install console-setup
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

and (I think) after that, ubuntu 16.04 started hanging on boot:
[image]

There is a `Failed to start Set console font and keymap`, but the last line is "Started Console Manager". I waited 15 minutes and nothing happened. I can provide every necessary info from recovery, so could you help me to fix this?

**Edit:**
Output of `systemctl status console-setup.service`:
[image]

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as solved.  It avoids confusion and it might be useful to someone later.

Comment: @bc2946088 ok, I will accept answer after 2 days, because now I can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After running this:

```
apt remove --purge console-setup
apt install console-setup
dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

failed log disappear and services was running.

Anyway after "Started Console Manager" nothing happened and I discovered in /var/log/apt/history.log that unity was uninstalled when I was installing console-common. After installing it with `apt install unity` system boot normally :)

Comment: Had the same problem.  Your suggestions solved the problem, thanks!